# Swipe/Fling on TextView also runs its onLongClick randomly

Tags: android, textview, swipe, touch-event, onlongclicklistener

I have an activity in which I want to be able to listen to swipes on it. There is a `ScrollView` inside my activity and a large `TextView` has filled all area of that ScrollView. To enable swipe on my whole ativity, I extended `Activity` class and defined `SwipeActivity` like this:

```
public abstract class SwipeActivity extends Activity {

private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY;
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new SwipeDetector());
    ViewConfiguration configuration = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
    SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = configuration.getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity();
}

private class SwipeDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {

        // Check movement along the Y-axis. If it exceeds
        // SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH,
        // then dismiss the swipe.
        if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
            return false;

        // Swipe from right to left.
        // The swipe needs to exceed a certain distance (SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE)
        // and a certain velocity (SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY).
        if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            leftSwipe();
            return true;
        }

        // Swipe from left to right.
        // The swipe needs to exceed a certain distance (SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE)
        // and a certain velocity (SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY).
        if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            rightSwipe();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // TouchEvent dispatcher.
    if (gestureDetector != null) {
        if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev))
            // If the gestureDetector handles the event, a swipe has been
            // executed and no more needs to be done.
            return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

protected abstract void rightSwipe();

protected abstract void leftSwipe();
}
```

Now I can capture `rightSwipe()` and `leftSwipe()` on any activity which extends SwipeActivity. So, I declared my main activity like this:

```
public class ContentActivity extends SwipeActivity implements OnLongClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Here I add a TextView programmatically to my Vertical ScrollView and set this activity to listen to its long clicks (touches)
        ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.content_scroll);
        TextView textView = new TextView(ContentActivity.this);
        textView.setText("Some Really Long Text!");
        textView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        scrollView.addView(textView);
    }      

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        return doLongClickAction();
    }

    @Override
    public void rightSwipe() {
        doSwipeAction();
    }

    @Override
    public void leftSwipe() {
        doSwipeAction();
    }

}
```

Now, everything appears fine and vertical `scrollView` scrolls correctly and swipe actions and long clicks work on `textView`, except one thing:

**from about 10 times which I swipe on the `textView`, 3 times it launches both `doLongClickAction()` and `doSwipeAction()` which is not friendly to user at all.**

I know my problem is something related to collision of touch events, but after hours studying and testing, I couldn't solve it. Would you please tell me where is my mistake?

*(I should add this: when I capture clicks instead of long-clicks on the TextView, everything is ok, but when user clicks on links inside textview, onClick event of textview is launched and then browser opens!)*